# How to explode quantiles in hive

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql

I am trying to get quantiles of a field and I want to explode them so that each value is a separate row rather than all of them forming a single array. First, I calculate 20 quantiles as below:

```
select percentile_approx(probability, 
                                       array(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 
                                             0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 
                                             0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0)) as quantiles
from my_table
```

The above code gives the array below:

> [0.17808226409449213, 0.18250386256254247, 0.18525207046272224, 0.18800918537059694, 0.1907743631982954, 0.200154288105411, 0.30419108474685375, 0.3299437131426226, 0.352433633041806, 0.3589875791100745, 0.37581775428218006, 0.3825168120904496, 0.3966342376441502, 0.4173753044627164, 0.43268994899295316, 0.44015098935735575, 0.461413042176578, 0.4720422104416653, 0.487852850513824, 0.5050010622123932]

But since I wanted to explode it, I tried using lateral view posexplode like below (actually, I passed the output from the above code):

```
select i, x
lateral view posexplode([0.17808226409449213, 0.18250386256254247,0.18525207046272224, 0.18800918537059694, 
                    0.1907743631982954, 0.200154288105411, 0.30419108474685375, 0.3299437131426226, 
                    0.352433633041806, 0.3589875791100745, 0.37581775428218006, 0.3825168120904496, 
                    0.3966342376441502, 0.4173753044627164, 0.43268994899295316, 0.44015098935735575, 
                    0.461413042176578, 0.4720422104416653, 0.487852850513824, 0.5050010622123932]) q as i, x
```

but it gives the error message below:

> ParseException: "\nextraneous input '[' expecting {'(', ')', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'ANY', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'PIVOT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', 'EXTRACT', '+', '-', '*', 'DIV', '~', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', STRING, BIGINT_LITERAL, SMALLINT_LITERAL, TINYINT_LITERAL, INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, DOUBLE_LITERAL, BIGDECIMAL_LITERAL, IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 3, pos 24)\n\n== SQL ==\n\nselect i, x\nlateral view posexplode([0.17808226409449213, 0.18250386256254247,0.18525207046272224, 0.18800918537059694, \n------------------------^^^\n                        0.1907743631982954, 0.200154288105411, 0.30419108474685375, 0.3299437131426226, \n                        0.352433633041806, 0.3589875791100745, 0.37581775428218006, 0.3825168120904496, \n                        0.3966342376441502, 0.4173753044627164, 0.43268994899295316, 0.44015098935735575, \n                        0.461413042176578, 0.4720422104416653, 0.487852850513824, 0.5050010622123932]) q as i, x\n"

On the other hand, if I create the array inside posexplode like below, it works fine:

```
select i, x
lateral view posexplode(array('a', 'b', 'c')) q as i, x
```

```
|  i|  x|
+---+---+
|  0|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  2|  c|
+---+---+
```

Comment: You cannot create array using square brackets. Such syntax is not suported. Use array() instead as in your last query.

Comment: That is the output from the first code chunk. It creates the quantiles with square brackets.

Comment: what I basically want is lateral vie posexplode(percentile_approx(probability, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select s.*, e.i, e.x
from
    (
    select percentile_approx(probability, 
                               array(0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 
                                    0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 
                                    0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99)) as quantiles
    from my_table
    ) s lateral view outer posexplode (s.quantiles) e as i, x
;
```

Comment: does not work for me. could it be hive version issue